# PHP Arrays looping and creating multi dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of items listed bellow

```
array (
        [0] => array(
            'order' => 'order001', 
            'qty' => 90 
        ), 
        [1] => array(
            'order' => 'order002', 
            'qty' => 100 
        ) 
    )
```

I also have a quantity(Q) that is to be fetched from the list above and the array have to be looped from top to bottom without even skipping a single item.

The loop will go through the first item to see if it can get the total requested and if the first loop cant meet the total then the it will return the total(T) got from the first item store it somewhere and then move to the next item in the array with a new value which lets say its (Q-T) and see if can find the quantity in the next item.

Now the problem is i cant actually figure out how to make hold and return the array as a list like in the case below.

Lets say i need a total of 120.

```
Array(
        Array(
            'order' => 'order001',
            'qty' => 90
            ),
        Array(
            'order' => 'order002',
            'qty' => 30
        )
    );
```

Comment: And what is the logic for 3 or more elements?

Comment: The logic is the same it will have to go through the items until the condition is met which is the total by drawing from each item and a record of how much and from which item was drawn is recorded. Thanx

Comment: Show what you have tried.. Code..?

Comment: What happen if no combination can come up with the total requested?

Comment: Sounds like a *0-1 knapsack problem*, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem!

Comment: If combination is not found then the result of the array will not have met the condition which is an expected case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?
https://iconoun.com/demo/temp_tonywiz.php

```html
<?php // demo/temp_tonywiz.php
/**
 * Working with arrays
 *
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264342/php-arrays-looping-and-creating-multi-dimensional-arrays
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';


$qty = 120;
$arr = [ ['order' => 'order001', 'qty' => 90], ['order' => 'order002', 'qty' => 100] ];
$out = [];

foreach ($arr as $sub)
{
    if ($qty <= 0) break;
    if ($sub['qty'] <= $qty)
    {
        $out[] = $sub;
        $qty = $qty - $sub['qty'];
    }
    else
    {
        $sub['qty'] = $qty;
        $out[] = $sub;
    }
}
print_r($arr);
print_r($out);
```

Comment: This will not find a combination of items matching the desired total if the first item has a quantity of `$total` less `$x` (for example), but there are items with quantities greater than `$x` that would add up to `$total`. For example: `[110, 50, 40, 30]`.

Comment: Very nice and simple code.. I had figured out a way to make the code work although i went through a hell of a process. Thank you yours worked perfectly may be try this. How do I comment in code snippet?

Comment: This will not produce correct results in all cases.

Comment: As usual, the quality of any solution you may get will be directly dependent on the quality of the test cases you provide.  We don't know what we don't know about the test data set!